# array.sort behaving strangely with wallaby.js

Tags: javascript, wallaby.js

I have a function that constructs an array like, `[{index: 1}, {index: 4}, {index: 7}]`. The array is ordered by the objects' index value. I have narrowed the scope of the function to just a sorting of an array and wallaby indicates the order of the array is incorrect, however mocha continues to indicate passing tests.

The spec is:

```
import expect from 'expect';
import sort from './sort';

describe("Given an array", ()=> {
    let array;
    beforeEach(() => {
        array = [
            { index: 7, owner: 1 },
            { index: 2, owner: 1 },
            { index: 3, owner: 1 },
            { index: 5, owner: 1 },
            { index: 1, owner: 1 }
        ];
    });

    describe("When sorting the array of elements by id", () => {

        let actual;
        beforeEach(() => {
            actual = sort(array);
        });

        it('should order the array of objects by ascending id',()=> {
            let expected = [
                { index: 1, owner: 1 },
                { index: 2, owner: 1 },
                { index: 3, owner: 1 },
                { index: 5, owner: 1 },
                { index: 7, owner: 1 }
            ];

            expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
        });
    });
});
```

The implementation of sort.js is:

```
export default function(array){
   return array.sort((x, y) => { return x.index > y.index});
}
```

My wallaby config looks like:

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'test';

var wallabyWebpack = require('wallaby-webpack');
var packageConfig = require('./package.json');

module.exports = function(wallaby) {

  var specFilePattern = 'src/shared/**/*.spec.js';
  var srcFilePattern = 'src/shared/**/*.js*';

  var babelProcessor = wallaby.compilers.babel(packageConfig['babel']);

  var webpackPostProcessor = wallabyWebpack({
    resolve: {
          extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
      }
  });

  return {
    testFramework: 'mocha',
    debug: true,
    files: [
      { pattern: 'node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js', instrument: false },
      { pattern: srcFilePattern, load: false },
      { pattern: specFilePattern, ignore: true }
    ],
    tests: [
      { pattern: specFilePattern, load: false }
    ],
    compilers: {
      '**/*.js*': babelProcessor
    },
    postprocessor: webpackPostProcessor,
    bootstrap: function(){
      window.__moduleBundler.loadTests();
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Wallaby.js is using PhantomJs behind the scenes by default, which uses the same JavaScript engine that Safari does. And if you run this snippet in **Safari Dev Tools**:

[image: screen shot 2016-03-22 at 12 42 21 pm]

you'll notice that it also doesn't sort the array as expected. **Chrome Dev Tools** will show you a different result:

[image: screen shot 2016-03-22 at 12 42 43 pm]

So if you'd like your `sort` implementation to work **on all platforms**, you need to change it to be [compliant with the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and return `1`, `-1` or `0`, as opposed to just `true` or `false`.

So if you rewrite your sort function this way:

```
export default function (array) {
  return array.sort((x, y) => {
    if (x.index > y.index) {
      return 1;
    }
    if (x.index < y.index) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  });
```

then it will work everywhere. If you'd prefer a shorter (but a bit less readable) way, you may use this one:

```
export default function(array) {
  return array.sort((x, y) => +(x.index > y.index) || +(x.index === y.index) - 1);
}
```

If for some reason you would only like to support platforms where your original code works and wouldn't like to change it, then I suggest switching the default PhantomJs runner to the [Electron runner](http://wallabyjs.com/docs/integration/electron.html) that wallaby also supports. It uses V8 and your original code works fine with it.